# What is the most efficient way to get in-sync transform updates for an HTML5 DIV or CANVAS element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Canvas element (inside a DIV).  I want to get updates whenever it's transform state changes for the below transforms:

canvas to page, canvas to window, and canvas to screen(pixels).

Ideally in a more convenient and more efficient way than setting up an animation task and traversing up the tree on each frame, saving the old values and comparing with the current state on every node from child to root and on every frame.

Comment: Do you have a limit on what could change this? Do you go as far as DOM changes? Or even as far as CSS transitions/animations? Or even as far as an image element just loaded and did change the page's layout? => Poll... (no need to walk the DOM though) You are in a scenario where a limited set of events may happen? Then tell us what they are.

Comment: Ideally I would be notified if ANYTHING changes the transform between the element and the page and the page and the window.

I'm sort of looking for something like onResize() but reporting that the transform has changed, I can then get the new values.

The basic things that can change it seem to be scrolling/panning/zooming of any parent element between the monitored element and the root window, and layout changes that woudl move it around on the page.  

I can exclude rotations, shears, and non uniform scaling. 

Can one get these two relative transforms without walking up the tree ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have an event when anything changes your Element's, the best is to poll every rendering frame (we can hook to these frames with the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method).

Such a polling would anyway be necessary to determine if the window has been moved in screen, since no built-in event does fire. (Note that browsers even seem to update it at a very low rate).

The basic is then to store an object holding your current Element's position (its [bounding box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) should be enough), along with the window's position (Window's `screenX`and `screenY` will let us know this), and to check every frame if the values did change.

One caveat is that the bounding box is relative to the Element's owner document only. That is, in a case like StackOverflow StackSnippets iframe, if we scroll the top most document, our element's bounding rect inside its iframe will not change. To overcome this, we can add an IntersectionObserver, which will be bale to let us know when the parent window is scrolled **when the Element is visible**.

```js
function listenForMove(elem) {

  if (!(elem instanceof Element))
    throw new TypeError('Expected an Element');

  const state = {
    width: null,
    height: null,
    left: null,
    top: null,
    screenX: null,
    screenY: null
  };
  let changed = false;

  function loop() {

    const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    Object.keys(state).forEach(checkKeys.bind(rect));
    ['screenX', 'screenY'].forEach(checkKeys.bind(window));

    if (changed) {
      elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('move'));
    }

    // lower the flag
    changed = false;
    // check again next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    function checkKeys(key) {
      if (key in this) {
        if (state[key] !== null && state[key] !== this[key]) {
          changed = true;
        }
        state[key] = this[key];
      }
    }

  }
  loop();

  // if inside a frame, our bounding box doesn't change
  // so we use an intersection observer
  // works only when the Element is visible though
  var obs = new IntersectionObserver(onintersectionchange, {
    root: null,
    margin: '100%',
    threshold: Array.from({
      length: 100
    }).map((_, i) => i / 100)
  })
  obs.observe(elem);

  function onintersectionchange(entries) {
    changed = true; // simply raise the flag
    // `loop` will be responsible of firing the event
  }

}


// initialise our poll loop
listenForMove(canvas);

canvas.addEventListener('move', e => console.log('moved'));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
}

canvas:hover {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  transition: .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: As I thought - one has to have an animation task and traverse the transforms up the tree to get the full story.

Comment: @peterk there is not tree traversal here, what do you mean?

Comment: not in your code - but if each parent can have a different scale lets say from the leaf to the root to get the cumulative scale from leaf to root (leaf to window, or leaf to screen) one much check up the tree and concatenate all the transforms. From what I know in the general case every node can have a transform.  And from what I presume if you get the transform from a node it only gives you the relative transform between it and it's parent (container) Or if the browser caches the total transform for speedy rendering on every node maybe there is a way to read it ?

Comment: @peterk of course every element has its computed bounding box, that's at least required by the CSS renderer and won't be done again if it didn't change since last time it's been calculated.

Comment: is this always in window coordinates without any scaling applied ? ( I assume if there is any general transform it is the "axis aligned" bounding box )

But to get from a location in the element to the window (or screen) coordinates one needs the full concatenated transform.

Comment: @peterk what do you mean by scaling? Why would there be no scaling? Can you do a bit of search on CSS rendering and [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) please? As to the screen relative position it's only the screenY and screenX properties that gives it to us. All the other coordinates are relative to the viewport.

Comment: I just read the stacking contexts document - it does not mention anything about non-translation transforms. Ie: what happens if an element is "rotated".   I assume in that case the bounding box is then derived from the four corners of the element "quad" as the min/max x and y values in viewport coordinates.

The docs don't yet have explicit info about how the un-transformed 2D legacy dom is evolving toward a genralized scene graph and how one handles it.  Hence my questions to see if any "experts" have the nice succinct answers that are possible. :)

Comment: Stacking context are on the Z axis... 2d transforms are made on a single 3×3 matrix: [scaleX, skewX, skewY, scaleY, translateX, translateY] there is no rotate or translate or scale alone, they're all linked and represented on the single matrix transform. We can't teach all the basics of graphics computation from this single unrelated question. You must do your own research.

Comment: Note I know my graphics, I led the team to create caligari truespace - you are right. I am assuming the DOM tree *can* now be a fully transform tree scene graph with full 3d transforms I just wanted an easy way to get the "local to root" transform for a dom element and get notified if it changes :)